# PHP file ignoring bootstrap table design

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, bootstrap-4

I am trying to retrieve data from a database and display it on the PHP file using the following code:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <title>Control Panel</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <link href="css/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="css/green.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Datatables -->
    <link href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/scroller.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
    <link href="css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
      <div class="main_container">
        <div class="col-md-12 left_col">
          <div class="left_col scroll-view">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_content">
                    <?php
                    $count_rows = 0;
                    include 'database_connection.php';
                    $sql = "SELECT date, ip, activate FROM software";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    echo "<table id='datatable-buttons class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
                          <tr>
                          <th>S/N</th>
                          <th>Date</th>
                          <th>IP Address</th>
                          <th>Activation</th>
                          </tr>";
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $count_rows++;
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $count_rows . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['ip'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['activate'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    mysqli_close($conn);
                    ?>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <script src="js/nprogress.js"></script>
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <script src="js/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Datatables -->
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/responsive.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
    <script src="js/custom.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting the results but it's not properly formatted. With almost the same code I can get the design but not the data: Here's the code that is working but not showing the data.

**index.html** (Incomplete code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Control Panel</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <link href="css/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="css/green.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Datatables -->
    <link href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/scroller.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
    <link href="css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
      <div class="main_container">
        <div class="col-md-12 left_col">
          <div class="left_col scroll-view">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_content">
                    <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>S/N</th>
                          <th>Date</th>
                          <th>IP Address</th>
                          <th>Activation</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>;
                    <td> $row['id'] </td>
                    <td> $row['date'] </td>
                    <td> $row['ip'] </td>
                    <td> $row['activate'] </td>
                    </tr>
                     </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <script src="js/nprogress.js"></script>
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <script src="js/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Datatables -->
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/responsive.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
    <script src="js/custom.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Of course I know that the index.html code is Incorrect or incomplete. However it does load the bootstrap table design perfectly. What am I doing on the PHP file?

Please guide me here.

Screenshot of index.php : http://oi65.tinypic.com/z7ed3.jpg

Screenshot of index.html: http://oi68.tinypic.com/2zqqvc6.jpg

Comment: You forgot to close the `</table>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your code in index.php file:

```
<table id='datatable-buttons class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
```

to

```
<table id='datatable-buttons' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
```

you didn't close quote after id `datatable-buttons`
and add `</table>` after the end of `while` block

In your case, you can change your code to code below:

```
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>S/N</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>IP Address</th>
        <th>Activation</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>        
    <tbody>

    <?php
    $count_rows = 0;
    include 'database_connection.php';
    $sql = "SELECT `date`, `ip`, `activate` FROM `software`";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
        $count_rows++;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $count_rows ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ip']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['activate']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. It works like a charm, Thank you.